# FFMPEG fix broken stream headers?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a couple of video files (.tsv) from the same recording device. One file seems to have broken headers, ffmpeg reports

> "dimensions not set"

and

> "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec
>   parameters)",

the other is ok. Is there any way to instruct ffmpeg (or any other software that may help) to use headers / video parameters from user options or from the other file?

ffmpeg output for broken video:

```
H:\PVR\TV> ffmpeg.exe -i "TV(152420).TSV" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "d:\TVP(152420).mp4"
ffmpeg version N-82966-g6993bb4 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable
-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-li
bbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enabl
e-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-li
bopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en
able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable
-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zl
ib
  libavutil      55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavcodec     57. 70.100 / 57. 70.100
  libavformat    57. 61.100 / 57. 61.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 68.100 /  6. 68.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] no frame!

/repeated a few times/

[h264 @ 000000000058f040] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000000000058f040] no frame!
[mpegts @ 000000000058a9a0] DTS discontinuity in stream 5: packet 14 with DTS 8279617306, packet 15 with DTS 8590342112
[mpegts @ 000000000058a9a0] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mpegts @ 000000000058a9a0] start time for stream 4 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 000000000058a9a0] start time for stream 7 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 000000000058a9a0] PES packet size mismatch
    Last message repeated 3 times
[mpegts @ 000000000058a9a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none): u
nspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 000000000058a9a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 6 (Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)): unknow
n codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'TVP(152420).TSV':
  Duration: 02:40:37.93, start: 91995.111844, bitrate: 3550 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x66]: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x67](pol): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 160 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x69](pol): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:3[0x68](qaa): Audio: eac3 (EAC3 / 0x33434145), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x6a](pol): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:5[0x6c](aux): Audio: eac3 (EAC3 / 0x33434145), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (visual impaired)
    Stream #0:6[0x6b]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:7[0x6d](eng): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
  Program 2
  Program 21
  Program 31
  Program 32
  Program 33
  Program 34
  Program 35
[mp4 @ 00000000032cd500] dimensions not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Meanwhile, the other file from the same transmission goes through similar "no frame" messages, to finish with successful stream identification.

```
[h264 @ 00000000004cf040] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000004cf040] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 00000000004cf040] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000004cf040] non-existing SPS 0 referenced in buffering period
[h264 @ 00000000004cf040] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 00000000004cf040] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000004cf040] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000004cf040] no frame!
[mpegts @ 00000000004ca9a0] start time for stream 4 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 00000000004ca9a0] start time for stream 7 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 00000000004ca9a0] PES packet size mismatch
    Last message repeated 3 times
[mpegts @ 00000000004ca9a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 6 (Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'TV(152420)_001.TSV':
  Duration: 01:02:17.92, start: 6188.060000, bitrate: 5877 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : TV1
      service_provider: xxx
    Stream #0:0[0x66]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x67](pol): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 160 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x69](pol): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / x0006)
    Stream #0:3[0x68](qaa): Audio: eac3 (EAC3 / 0x33434145), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x6a](pol): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / x0006)
    Stream #0:5[0x6c](aux): Audio: eac3 (EAC3 / 0x33434145), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (visual impaired)
    Stream #0:6[0x6b]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:7[0x6d](eng): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / x0006)
  Program 2
    Metadata:
      service_name    : TV2
      service_provider: xxx
  Program 3
    Metadata:
      service_name    : TV3
      service_provider: xxx
```

Comment: (the broken file plays sound with mpc-hq but has no video)

Comment: Try `ffmpeg.exe -analyzeduration 100M -probesize 1G -i "TV(152420).TSV" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "d:\TVP(152420).mp4"`

Comment: Also try "ffmpeg -f h264" to specify the codec before you specify the input file.

Comment: don't use -f h264, that will specify the container, which isn't annexb ("h264") but mpeg-ts.